# How can I tell Visual Studio to use the project directory instead of the current file directory when including files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am refactoring my Visual-Studio-C++ project to use a folder structure rather than the filters in Visual Studio but I have noticed that when I try to include a file, it will use the current directory of that file so my includes look something like...

```
#include "../../server/IGameServer.h"
```

This is quite problematic when I refactor and move things around as I then have to go into each file and change their includes...

Is there a way to make every file start from the base directory no matter where the current file is, or a way to include the folder path so I can just use
`#include "IGameServer.h"`

Comment: I can do this by adding the `$(ProjectDir)` macro to the additional includes, but that still means I have to the entire path to the header. Is there a way to automatically include all subfolders in a directory?

Comment: Yeah, don't do that.  Proper way is Project > Properties > C/C++ > General > "Additional Include Directories" setting.

Comment: @HansPassant is this even for folders in the same project? I thought this was for additional includes such as external libraries?

Comment: Puzzling comment, there is only one project folder.  Guessing somewhat, If you #include a .h file that lives in Timbuktu and it has an #include that needs to be found in the current project folder then you must add `"."` to the additional include directories setting.  Best avoided, but it happens.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Go to project properties:
And add folders to "Addiotional Include Directories". *...Make sure that you aply to "All Configurations" (Debug, Release, etc.) and "All Platforms" (X86, X64).*

[image]

--

(2) Click on that line + one more click on right side, on the down-arrow) & click `Edit...`. It opens a dialog that looks like that (I already added some folders in this example):

[image]